How to post multiple request at the same time in Jmeter as 1 instances?
Hi I'm new to Jmeter I have this Http Request here that will create 1 item when i post it (https://i.sstatic.net/QsZxPz6n.png).
And when put it like this it will create 2 items instead
(https://i.sstatic.net/nuLsMQHP.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/2rxnTkM6.png)
What I want to achieve is to be able Post multiple item at once.
I've tried using loop controller
(https://i.sstatic.net/7oTIimqe.png)
but the result it gave me is posting 1 items for 10 times.
Is there a way that I can post 10 items at once with only 1 user counts?

Let me rephrase your request : "you want 10 items created in a single HTTP request, and you want that JMeter duplicates the items in the HTTP request body to do that" ? Is that correct ? Or do you want 10 HTTP requests ?

yes 10 items within a single HTTP request is this doable?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Must your 10 items in your body be dynamic (not the same 10 items in a single http request) ? You want to load test a bulk create endpoint ? What is your input for the item values ? csv file ?

If you want to run the same request i.e. 10 times at the same moment:

In Thread Group set "Number of Threads" to 10


Add a Synchronizing Timer to your Test Plan and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to 10


This way JMeter will run each Sampler in the Synchronizing Timer's scope with 10 threads at exactly the same moment of time.
More information: A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers
